# Useful matrix inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, big-list

What are some interesting/useful examples of matrix inner products on square complex matrices, other than $\langle A, B \rangle = Tr(A^{\dagger}B)$?

Comment: The Killing form on a Lie algebra of square matrices, given by $\langle A,B \rangle =Tr(ad(x)ad(y)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The Killing form is bilinear rather than biHermitian over complex spaces, and it fails to satisfy $B[x,x] > 0$ for $x \neq 0$.  So, calling it an inner product seems like a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find anything as useful as the one you mention, but this might be of interest.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115192/power-log-distance-between-matrices/115227#115227
(ps. again I would have made this a comment rather than an answer, but I still can't do that)